# Как реализовать Alt+TAB

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

В окне формы ввожу логин и пароль, затем selenium заходит на сайт, авторизуется, забирает необходимые данные и записывает их в comboBox1 на этой же форме. Пользователь должен самостоятельно выбрать значение из comboBox1, после чего программа продолжит свою работу. Selenium запускает браузер, форма сворачивается. Можно как-нибудь программно реализовать Alt+TAB, чтобы не переключать окна руками.
То есть я хочу, чтобы после добавления всех элементов в comboBox1 на экране снова появилось окно формы.

Comment: а почему не используете метод SHOW? По сути организовывая нажатие Alt+TAB, вы не гарантируете переход к нужному окну. Да и потом можно ведь создать несколько контролов, и сворачивать внутри окна именно их, а не окна.

Comment: Не совсем верно написал. Окно формы не сворачивается, а остается за окном браузера, поэтому Show использовать не получилось.

Comment: А кто вам мешает в форму встроить браузер?

Comment: Другой вариант, закрыть браузер.

Comment: Закрытие браузера приведет к остановке программы, так как он открыт seleniumом, а WebBrowser не обладает необходимым функционалом.

Comment: _остается за окном браузера_ - Попробуйте свойству [TopMost](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=netframework-4.7.2) вашей формы задать значение `true`. После чего желательно вернуть его в `false`.